# Why do we need to use random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In my statistics textbook (The Practice of Statistics by Starnes, Yates, and Moore) an example is given. In it, 21 students are each given three glasses of water. Two are filled with tap water and one is filled with bottled water. The students are asked to identify which of the cups holds the bottled water.

The textbook then states that if there is no distinction between bottled water and tap water, the chance that the student guesses the cup with the bottled water is 1/3. The textbook then goes on to say that to find the probability that 13 of the 21 students would guess correctly you need random variables.

However, wouldn't the probability be $\tfrac 1 3\cdot\tfrac 1 3\cdot\tfrac 1 3\cdot\tfrac 1 3\cdot\tfrac 1 3\cdot\tfrac 1 3\cdot\tfrac 1 3\cdot\tfrac 1 3\cdot\tfrac 1 3\cdot\tfrac 1 3\cdot\tfrac 1 3\cdot\tfrac 1 3\cdot\tfrac 1 3$ or $\tfrac 1 {3^{13}}$?

If not, why is that and why do we need random variables?

Comment: The probability is much larger than that. You have computed the probability that $13$ out of $13$ would guess correctly.

Comment: For such simple problem you can avoid the notion of random variable using only combinatorics. Assume answer is 1,2,3 where 1 is correct. From all possible student answers (3^21 21-length number that contains only 1,2,3) find number of answers with $13$  $1$s.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that 13 of 21 students guess correctly is: $\dfrac{21!}{13!8!}\dfrac{2^8}{3^{21}}$

By reason that: the favourable case is 13 guess correctly ($p=\tfrac 13$), 8 guess wrongly ($1-p=\tfrac23$), and there are $^{21}C_{13}$ ways to select the thirteen students.

This is a Binomial Distribution $G\sim{\cal Bin}(21, \frac 13) \iff P(G=k) = {^{21}C_k}(1-\tfrac{1}{3})^{21-k}(\tfrac 1 3)^k$

The reason we use well know distributions when we can recognise them, is that their properties are well known.

---

$\dfrac 1 {3^{13}}$ would be the probability that *all of the first* thirteen students correctly identified the solution.